# Eliminar numero en una Lista

Tags: java

Consiste en eliminar los números consecutivos de una **lista** incluido el primer numero, solo se puede resolver mediante un juego de **nodos**, en eso consiste principalmente el ejercicio, en mejorar la algorítmica, pero me he visto con un problema que no logro resolver, consigo borrar los números consecutivos pero el residuo que queda no consigo eliminarlo. Es decir si tengo el numero **1 2 2 2 3** mi salida es **1 2 3** y no consigo que mi salida sea **1 3**.

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme a entender como hacerlo o en que fallo lo agradecería para aprender para próximos problemas semejantes que se me presenten

**Clase Lista**

```
public class Lista {

    private Nodo com;

    public Lista() {

        this.com = null;

    }

    public Nodo getCom() {

        return com;

    }

    public void setCom(Nodo com) {

        this.com = com;

    }

    public boolean listaVacia() {

        return com == null;

    }

    public void insertarPrincipio(int info) {

        Nodo p = new Nodo ();
        p.setInfo(info);
        p.setSig(com);
        com = p;

    }

    public Lista llenar() {

        int aux [] = {1,2,2,2,3,4,4,6,7,7,8,1,2};

        for(int i=aux.length-1; i>=0; i--) {

            this.insertarPrincipio(aux[i]);

        }

        return this;

    }

    public void elmininarConsecutivoIncluido() {

        Nodo p = com;

        while(p.getSig()!=null) {

            if(p.getInfo()==p.getSig().getInfo()) {

                p.setSig(p.getSig().getSig());

            }else {

                p = p.getSig();

            }

        }

    }

    public String toString () {

        Nodo p = com;

        String s = "";

        if(listaVacia()==false) {

            while(p!=null) {

                s = s + p.getInfo() + " ";

                p = p.getSig();

            }

        }

        return s;


    }

}
```

**Clase Nodo**

```
public class Nodo {

    private int info;
    private Nodo sig;

    public Nodo() {

        this.info = info;
        this.sig = sig;

    }

    public Nodo(int info) {

        this.info = info;
        this.sig = sig;

    }

    public int getInfo() {

        return info;

    }

    public void setInfo(int info) {

        this.info  = info;

    }

    public Nodo getSig() {

        return sig;

    }

    public void setSig(Nodo sig) {

        this.sig = sig;

    }

}
```

**Clase Main**

```
public class Ejercicio1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Lista l1 = new Lista ();

        l1.llenar(); 

        System.out.println(l1.toString());

        l1.elmininarConsecutivoIncluido();

        System.out.println(l1.toString());


    }

}
```

Comment: Una vez que has eliminado dos "2" ¿qué valor retornará `(p.getInfo()==p.getSig().getInfo())`? En todo caso iría bien que miraras como funciona un depurador para ver en más detalle lo que hace tu código.

Comment: Mi salida retorna los números sin sus consecutivos, y la salida debería ser eliminar todo numero que le siga un consecutivo incluido el mismo.

Comment: Entiendo que eso es lo que QUIERES. Lo que yo te explico te indica qué es lo que HACE (cuando solo queda un elemento ya no es "consecutivo"). Como te comento, ejecuta el código paso por paso con un depurador y verás el problema. Cuando lo veas, verás porqué no es un problema de una instrucción que no funcione sino que el algoritmo no sirve para lo que quieres.